# php code being printed in html

Tags: php, html

This is the PHP code for logging the user into the website which I am building but whenever  I run this code I am getting the following output. Please help me.

I am using WAMP server, short open tag is enabled.

OUTPUT

> wrong password'; } } else { echo 'invalid username'; } } ?> `

THIS IS THE PHP CODE

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name'])){

//connecting to data base 

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost:3306","root","","recommender");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{

echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

}


  $q = "select * from user where name ='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'])."'";
  $res = mysql_query($q) or die("wrong query");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
  if(!empty($row))
{
    if($_POST['password']==$row['password'])
    {
        $_SESSION['name']=$_POST['name'];
        header('Localhost/home.html');
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<centre><font color="red">wrong password</font></centre>';

    }
}
else
{
    echo '<centre><font color="red">invalid username</font></centre>';

}

}
?>
```

Comment: The weird-looking syntax highlighting here should be a hint…

Comment: Is there a reason you have "<br>" on most of the lines? Is that actually a part of your code?

Comment: @duskwuff: Yeah, friends don't let friends code without syntax highlighting. P.S.: Is `<centre>` valid HTML? I think the spec calls for `<center>`...

Comment: it was a mistake done while posting the question ..sorry for that ..but  still i am getting the same output .. please help me ..

Answer (score 1):

you have a syntax error on

```
$q = "select * from user where name ='.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'])."'";<br>
                                     ^^ lost "
```

solve this with

```
$q = "select * from user where name = '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']) . "'";
```

Comment: still i am getting the same error..

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
$q = "select * from user where name ='.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'])."'";<br>
```

to

```
$q = "select * from user where name = `".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'])."` LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: You never mentioned an error.  I don't see anything else wrong with the syntax, what is the error you're receiving?

Comment: the same output is being printed.

Comment: could you do a `var_dump($q);` for us?

Comment: again the same output was printed sir ..

Comment: But what does $q print?  It shouldn't be null.  `var_dump($q)` will tell us if PHP is interpreting your query statement correctly, or if there's more errors in the syntax.